#  How do I retrieve a friend list from Facebook and show it in a table view?

Tags: iphone

How do I retrieve a friend list from Facebook and show it in a table view in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hii,

Write a FQL to extract User friend List,

```
NSString *query = @"SELECT uid, name, pic_square, status FROM user WHERE uid IN (";
query = [query stringByAppendingFormat:@"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %@)",self.uid];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              query, @"query",
                              nil];
[_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                     andParams: params
                 andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                   andDelegate: self];
```

Hope this Helps!!!